# firebase_auth: 'UserAgent.h' file not found

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

When I trying to get the iOS file, there's below error. In settings, mode is debug and platform is iOS
I tried many ways to overcome this. But can't find any way. I have windows PC, not the mac. This app is perfectly work on android. I want to get deploy this app to the ios.

```
Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before 
deploying to device.
Building com.sevensynco.jewtube for device (ios)...
Upgrading project.pbxproj

Running pod install...                                          
107.7s

Running Xcode build...                                          

Xcode build done.                                           134.3s

Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1462:38: warning: variable 'sum_left' may be 
uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
    const uint16x8_t sum = vaddq_u16(sum_left, sum_top);
                                     ^~~~~~~~
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1426:3: note: variable 'sum_left' is declared here
  uint16x8_t sum_left;
  ^
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1462:48: warning: variable 'sum_top' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
    const uint16x8_t sum = vaddq_u16(sum_left, sum_top);
                                               ^~~~~~~
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1425:3: note: variable 'sum_top' is declared here
  uint16x8_t sum_top;
  ^
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1546:38: warning: variable 'sum_left' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
    const uint16x8_t sum = vaddq_u16(sum_left, sum_top);
                                     ^~~~~~~~
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1510:3: note: variable 'sum_left' is declared here
  uint16x8_t sum_left;
  ^
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1546:48: warning: variable 'sum_top' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
    const uint16x8_t sum = vaddq_u16(sum_left, sum_top);
                                               ^~~~~~~
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1509:3: note: variable 'sum_top' is declared here
  uint16x8_t sum_top;
  ^
4 warnings generated.
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:663:12: warning: variable 'best_offset' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
          (best_offset << MAX_LENGTH_BITS) | (uint32_t)best_length;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:595:20: note: initialize the variable 'best_offset' to silence this warning
    int best_offset;
                   ^
                    = 0
1 warning generated.
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1462:38: warning: variable 'sum_left' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
    const uint16x8_t sum = vaddq_u16(sum_left, sum_top);
                                     ^~~~~~~~
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1426:3: note: variable 'sum_left' is declared here
  uint16x8_t sum_left;
  ^
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1462:48: warning: variable 'sum_top' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
    const uint16x8_t sum = vaddq_u16(sum_left, sum_top);
                                               ^~~~~~~
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1425:3: note: variable 'sum_top' is declared here
  uint16x8_t sum_top;
  ^
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1546:38: warning: variable 'sum_left' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
    const uint16x8_t sum = vaddq_u16(sum_left, sum_top);
                                     ^~~~~~~~
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1510:3: note: variable 'sum_left' is declared here
  uint16x8_t sum_left;
  ^
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1546:48: warning: variable 'sum_top' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
    const uint16x8_t sum = vaddq_u16(sum_left, sum_top);
                                               ^~~~~~~
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/dsp/dec_neon.c:1509:3: note: variable 'sum_top' is declared here
  uint16x8_t sum_top;
  ^
4 warnings generated.
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:663:12: warning: variable 'best_offset' may be uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
          (best_offset << MAX_LENGTH_BITS) | (uint32_t)best_length;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/libwebp/src/enc/backward_references_enc.c:595:20: note: initialize the variable 'best_offset' to silence this warning
    int best_offset;
                   ^
                    = 0
1 warning generated.
In file included from /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.m:26:
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param sharedStyle
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param allowTapToDismiss
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
 @param allowTapToDismiss
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
 @param allowTapToDismiss
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        tapToDismissEnabled
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param queueEnabled
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
4 warnings generated.
In file included from /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:2:
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param sharedStyle
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param allowTapToDismiss
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
 @param allowTapToDismiss
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
 @param allowTapToDismiss
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        tapToDismissEnabled
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param queueEnabled
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:19:23: warning: unused variable 'viewController' [-Wunused-variable]
    UIViewController *viewController =
                      ^
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:70:21: warning: unused variable 'topPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
            CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
                    ^
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:71:21: warning:
 unused variable 'bottomPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
            CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
                    ^
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:48:19: warning: unused variable 'size' [-Wunused-variable]
        NSNumber *size = call.arguments[@"size"];
                  ^
8 warnings generated.
In file included from /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.m:26:
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param sharedStyle
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param allowTapToDismiss
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
 @param allowTapToDismiss
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
 @param allowTapToDismiss
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        tapToDismissEnabled
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param queueEnabled
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
4 warnings generated.
In file included from /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:2:
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param sharedStyle
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param allowTapToDismiss
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
 @param allowTapToDismiss
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
 @param allowTapToDismiss
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        tapToDismissEnabled
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param queueEnabled
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:19:23: warning: unused variable 'viewController' [-Wunused-variable]
    UIViewController *viewController =
                      ^
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:70:21: warning: unused variable 'topPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
            CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
                    ^
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:71:21: warning: unused variable 'bottomPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
            CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
                    ^
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:48:19: warning: unused variable 'size' [-Wunused-variable]
        NSNumber *size = call.arguments[@"size"];
                  ^
8 warnings generated.
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_thumbnail-0.2.0/ios/Classes/VideoThumbnailPlugin.m:60:94: warning: values of type 'NSInteger' should not be used as format arguments; add an explicit cast to 'long' instead [-Wformat]
                result( [FlutterError errorWithCode:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %ld", error.code]
                                                                                       ~~~   ^~~~~~~~~~
                                                                                       %ld   (long)
1 warning generated.
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database-3.1.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseDatabasePlugin.m:13:79: warning: values of type 'NSInteger' should not be used as format arguments; add an explicit cast to 'long' instead [-Wformat]
  return [FlutterError errorWithCode:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %ld", error.code]
                                                                        ~~~   ^~~~~~~~~~
                                                                        %ld   (long)
1 warning generated.
/Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.4+2/darwin/Classes/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.m:6:9: fatal error: 'UserAgent.h' file not found
#import "UserAgent.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description

 ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 Building a deployable iOS app requires a selected Development Team with a 
 Provisioning Profile. Please ensure that a Development Team is selected by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
    open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
 in the project settings
 3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected. 
 - For Xcode 10, look under General > Signing > Team.
 - For Xcode 11 and newer, look under Signing & Capabilities > Team.
 You may need to:
     - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
     - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
     - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
     - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
    4- Build or run your project again

   For more information, please visit:
    https://flutter.dev/setup/#deploy-to-ios-devices

   Or run on an iOS simulator without code signing
  ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
  Encountered error while building for device.



  Build failed :|
  Failed to build for iOS
```

And below is the info.plist file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">

<dict>
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
 <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
 <true/>
 </dict>
  <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
 <array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
  </array>
 <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Explain why your app uses music</string>
  <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Explain why your app uses photo library</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>jewtube</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
  </dict>
 </plist>
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: seems you faced with firebase_auth issue https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2084

Answer (score -1):

It could be sometimes. Works when deintegrate pod.

```
cd ios
pod deintegrate
pod install
```